# fpdf insert new line in a string

Tags: php, newline, fpdf

I  would like to insert "new line" in a string used with fpdf. Here under the code where new line is not inserted.

```
if (strlen($value['article']) > 25){
    $article = substr_replace($value['article'],'\n',24,0);         
    $pdf->MultiCell(35,4,utf8_decode($article),'1','L',0);
}
else {
    $pdf->MultiCell(35,8,utf8_decode($value['article']),'1','L',0);
}
```

Where is my mistake ?

I just find the solution : if I replace simple-quote by double-quote, "\n" runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` :

```
if (strlen($value['article']) > 25){
   $article = substr_replace($value['article'],"\n",24,0);         
   $pdf->MultiCell(35,4,utf8_decode($article),'1','L',0);
}
else {
   $pdf->MultiCell(35,8,utf8_decode($value['article']),'1','L',0);
}
```

This is because PHP takes text in single quotes (') literally, while text contained in double quotes (") is 'interpreted'

Edit : And maybe the `utf8_decode` mess with the `\n` too

Comment: "\n" works with utf8_decode